# Why is ArgoCD confusing GitHub.com with my own public IP?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, argocd

I have just set up a kubernetes cluster on bare metal using kubeadm, Flannel and MetalLB. Next step for me is to install ArgoCD.

I installed the ArgoCD yaml from the "Getting Started" page and logged in.

When adding my Git repositories ArgoCD gives me very weird error messages:
[image]
The error message seems to suggest that ArgoCD for some reason is resolving github.com to my public IP address (I am not exposing SSH, therefore connection refused).

I can not find any reason why it would do this. When using https:// instead of SSH I get the same result, but on port 443.

I have put a dummy pod in the same namespace as ArgoCD and made some DNS queries. These queries resolved correctly.

What makes ArgoCD think that github.com resolves to my public IP address?

EDIT:

I have also checked for network policies in the argocd namespace and found no policy that was restricting egress.

I have had this working on clusters in the same network previously and have not changed my router firewall since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem!

My /etc/resolv.conf had two lines that caused trouble:

```
domain <my domain>
search <my domain>
```

These lines were put there as a step in the installation of my host machine's OS that I did not realize would affect me in this way. After removing these lines, everything is now working perfectly.

Multiple people told me to check resolv.conf, but I didn't realize what these two lines did until now.

Comment: @VonC thanks for your help. I really appreciate you taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [argoproj/argo-cd issue 1510](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/1510), where the initial diagnostic was that the cluster is blocking outbound connections to GitHub. And it suggested to check the egress configuration.

Yet, the issue was resolved with an  ingress rule configuration:

> need to define in `values.yaml`.
> `argo-cd` default provide subdomain but in our case it was `/argocd`

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  path: /argocd
  hosts:
    - www.example.com
```

> and this I have defined under `templates >> argocd-server-deployment.yaml`

```yaml
containers: 
  - name: argocd-server 
    image: {{ .Values.server.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.server.image.tag }} 
    imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.server.image.pullPolicy }} 
    command: 
      - argocd-server 
      - --staticassets - /shared/app - --repo-server - argocd-repo-server:8081 - --insecure - --basehref - /argocd
```

The same case includes an [instance very similar to yours](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/1510#issuecomment-686780651):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48730712/92177232-b9839900-ee5d-11ea-844e-9a20c8e8ee4b.png]

In any case, do check your git configuration (`git config -l`) as seen in the ArgoCD cluster, to look for any `insteadOf` which would change automatically `github.com` into a local URL ([as seen here](https://rtfm.co.ua/arch-git-github-com-errnoconnection-refused/))

Comment: `kubectl exec --stdin --tty -n argocd argocd-repo-server-784b48858f-c57ch -- git config -l
Defaulted container "argocd-repo-server" out of: argocd-repo-server, copyutil (init)
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true`

Comment: I read the issue you linked to, but I do not understand what Ingress has to do with this? ArgoCD should just be connecting to github.com and pull the repo. There should be no Ingress. The connection should be initiated by ArgoCD, not github.com.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HannesKnutsson I agree. I don't understand it fully either. At least your git config does not seem to have any problematic setting.

Comment: Can you think of anything else I can do to figure this out? I have made this "bounty" question on stackoverflow, I have asked in the ArgoCD slack, I have made a bug report of my own and I have commented on the issue you found. I'm at my wits end here :(

Comment: @HannesKnutsson Try some linters like https://github.com/datreeio/datree or https://github.com/yannh/kubeconform, or KubeLinter (https://twitter.com/learnk8s/status/1332040255793483784), just to see if it detects some mis-configuration. That might give some clue as to why this egress connection is not working.